# How can I automate a (usually) interactive build script with Github Actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, expect, github-actions

I'm trying to add CI to a project that uses a set of build scripts written in bash.  The scripts prompt for input a few times for configuration information (setting flags, setting parameters, etc.)  Does Github Actions have its own commands for dealing with this, or is there a way to set up an expect script (or something similar)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no feature that allows prompting for manual input during workflow runs. See [this response](https://github.community/t/prompting-for-user-input-in-github-action/125838/2) on the community forums where a similar question was asked.

Here are some options you can explore:

1. Redesign the scripts to read from configuration files and check them into git to trigger the build.
2. Use the [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) event to create a workflow that you can manually trigger from the Actions UI and supply input parameters. See [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow) for more detail.
3. Use [slash-command-dispatch](https://github.com/peter-evans/slash-command-dispatch) to trigger the build using a slash command with arguments for the build's input parameters.